# Bitwise XOR (exclusive OR) in PHP

Tags: php, bitwise-operators, visual-foxpro

I need a function in PHP which does the same as

```
BITXOR(ASC("a"), 9)
```

does in Visual FoxPro 9 (the result is 104).

I don't code PHP ever, but the function XOR doesn't the same, I do:

```
ord($lcCaract) xor $lnKey
```

where $lcCaract = "a" and $lnKey = 9 and the result is 0.

Any help?

Comment: Did you try reading the documentation of [Bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)?

Comment: Or google "php xor". The Internet can answer your questions so easily, why are people so helpless?

Comment: @Barmar It seems that you (and I) have fallen onto deaf ears. I placed [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44318934/bitwise-xor-exclusive-or-in-php#comment75643899_44319245) under what the [OP posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44319245/1415724), but don't see it as being one and haven't responded to that neither. Am not quite sure if that should be flagged as "not an answer".

Answer (score 1):

> $a ^ $b   Xor (exclusive or)  Bits that are set in $a or $b but not both
>   are set.

so Try below

```
echo $result=ord('a') ^ 9;
```

`ord` Return the ASCII value in PHP  just like `ASC` in foxpro

Follow this http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php